# Используйте кеш браузера - рекомендация от Google

Tags: веб-программирование, кэширование, оптимизация-сайтов, cloudflare

Кучу всего перечитал по этому вопросу, а также кучу методов испробовал с htaccess, но сообщение "Используйте кеш браузера" не пропадает. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как это настраивается? Может можно на самом сервере настроить?

На сайте я использую https от cloudflare.com и там в настройках есть сжатие и контента и кеш браузера, но гугл на это не реагирует.

Comment: «но сообщение "Используйте кеш браузера" не пропадает» — было бы неплохо, если бы вы написали, что вы делаете, и кто выдаёт вам это сообщение

Answer (score 1):

По клику на ссылку "как исправить" у вас откроется перечень файлов, которые не прошли проверку по этому параметру. В конце в скобках указан срок действия кеша. Он должен быть минимум неделя, максимум - год. Подробнее об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching).

Если у вас в этом списке находятся внешние ресурсы, то пройти эту проверку вряд ли удастся.

Comment: Да, есть внешние ресурсы. Наверное в этом и дело. Спасибо.